# Coreutils on Ubuntu 14.0.3 is not working

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean

I keep trying to do the command "ls" and the console gives me back "The program 'ls' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install coreutils". I have tried installing coreutils and it says coreutils is already the newest version. "ls" still does not work. I am also using a digital ocean droplet. Thank you.[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqbQn.png)

Comment: Ubuntu version is 14.04.3. WHOOPS! PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just reinstalled coreutils.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install coreutils
```